CameraPreview in Flutter shows only streched image
Image of the CameraPreview
I implemented the same example as on the Package Page: https://pub.dev/packages/camera the controller also gets intialized correctly, but the preview doesn't show the image right. It seems like its overstreched. But every solution regarding aspect ratio has been tried but shouldn'T be needed if the Widget build looks like:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }

I use the Version: ^0.10.5

I found the problem. For some reason i was on the main channel of flutter on my workstation.
I switched to the stable channel and runned flutter clean and then rebuilt without the problem.
